# Does match query for elasticsearch go through lists? If not, what is the way to do this?

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

Assuming I have a document that is stored with the following...

```
{
'author':'John',
'books': {
'book1': {
'author':'John Williams'
},
'book2': {
'author':'Jacob Riley'
},
'booklist':[
'book1': {
'author':'John Williams'
},
'book2': {
'author':'Jacob Riley'
}
]
}
}
```

If a user performs a text search on say "Joe" on the field 'authors', does it search only on all of the fields including the ones in the books dict when results are returned? Or is it only looking at the 'author' field in the main list?

How could a user search on say only the 'author' field within 'booklist' or 'books'? What is the query string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, all your "author" fields are differents fields, ES-wise.
You have

```
author
books.book1.author 
books.book2.author 
etc, etc
```

See? with that json construct, they are all different fields.
Now, if you have a list like this one :

```
{

'booklist' : [{
               'idbook' : 'book1'
               'author' : 'John Williams'
              }, 
              {
               'idbook' : 'book2'
               'author' : 'Jacob Riley'
              }
             ]

 }
```

And do a search on the field booklist.author, it will indeed search in all the books in your list.
Be aware, tough, that if you search for several criterias in the same book, you take the risk of having cross-matches.

Fot instance, here, a search for idbook = 'book1' and author = 'jacob riley', your document will match. See nested type or parent-child to solve this.

Hope it helps.

Good luck.